# Iterating over a hashMap <String, String> key changes to BigDecimal

Tags: java, hashmap, bigdecimal

My issue is this, I have  hashMap

```
//for (String tablaBuscar : listaTablas) {
        // RECUPERAR REGISTROS POR TABLA
    HashMap<String,String> listaRegistros =(HashMap<String,String>) RequerimientosTablaDestino
                .getListaLineasPorTablaYColumna(idCabecera,idCriterio);
```

when I want to iterate (I have tried several ways, this is the last one)

```
Iterator<String>  entradaMap =  listaRegistros.keySet().iterator();
Iterator<String> valorMap =  listaRegistros.values().iterator();
while(entradaMap.hasNext()&&valorMap.hasNext()) {
    String elemento=entradaMap.next().toString();
    int registro =(Integer.parseInt(elemento));
    String tablaBuscar = (String)valorMap.next();
```

in "int registro" line I get "cannot cast from BigDecimal to Int" Debugging I have seen that ALLWAYS  the key of the hash map is "big decimal type", no matter the way I have created it.

If I try to use it as a BigDecimal as seen in debugging time, I get compilations failures because "type missmatch" "cannot cast" etc...

So the compiler thinks that the key is the type I have put, but at runtime the program thinks that te key is allways a bigDecimal.

Any idea?
thanks

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I can't see how you'd get the problem you're reporting on the line you're reporting it...

Answer (score 0):

If your key set only contains `String` values parseable as `BigDecimal`, you can easily retrieve an actual `BigDecimal` object from the keys by iterating them and using the constructor taking a `String` argument:

```
for (String key: myMap.keySet()) {
    BigDecimal converted = new BigDecimal(key);
}
```

Also as shown, no need for a double iteration through `Iterator` on both keys and values.

If you want an additional layer of validation, you can catch a `NumberFormatException` when initializing your `BigDecimal`, e.g. `new BigDecimal("foo")` would throw one.

Also, you can retrieve the integer value of your `BigDecimal` objects by invoking `BigDecimal#intValue` or `BigDecimal.intValueExact`.

Comment: Thanks, guys. The issue happened because ibatis parametrization has not the java type in resultMap. And (Idon't know why) it takes key as BigDecimal when is declared as String.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. Miguel alluded to the solution in his comment on Mena's answer, but to be more explicit the fix involves adding a parameter to your result mapper to force the return of a String:

```
<resultMap type="java.util.HashMap" id="dataTypeMap">
    <result column="DATA_TYPE_ID" javaType="java.lang.String" property="id" />
    <result column="DATA_TYPE" property="name" />
</resultMap>
```